# Unable to Center Edit Text in Android

Tags: android, xaml, user-interface

Im trying to create a simple login screen,i want the edit text to be centered. i tried setting `android:gravity="center"` but it does not work

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <TextView
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="300"
            android:orientation="center"
            android:layout_height="100"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="300"
            android:layout_height="30"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/editText1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: u want edit text to be center of the LinearLayoyt ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
android:layout_gravity="center"
```

instead of

```
 android:gravity="center"
```

Answer (score 1):

if you want text in centre use gravity and if edittext in centre use layout_gravity.

```
  <EditText
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_width="300"
    android:layout_height="30"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/editText1" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px">
        <TextView
            android:text="User Name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="300"
            android:orientation="center"
            android:layout_height="100"
             android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/textView1" />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:layout_width="300"
            android:layout_height="30"
            android:gravity="center"
           android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/editText1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

> and please try to specify the width in *dp

Answer (score 0):

Change from `android:gravity="center"` to `android:layout_gravity="center"`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minHeight="25dp"

    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="center"
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="asdfas"
        android:inputType="textPersonName" />
```

Also use Unit in Also `android:layout_width="300dp"` and `android:layout_height="30dp"`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `android:gravity="center_horizontal"` in your LinearLayout. your code will be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:text="User Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_width="300"
        android:layout_height="100"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
    <EditText
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="300"
        android:layout_height="30"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/editText1" />
</LinearLayout>
```